# How can I remove a column based on a satisfied condition on a row range?

Tags: python, pandas

I am pretty new into pandas and I would like to remove a column if it satifies a condition on a range of rows.

```
                  A         B         C         D  
  2017-01-01   0.132003 -0.827317 -0.076467 -1.187678
  2017-01-02   1.130127  NaN      -1.413681  
  2017-01-03   3.546974  NaN      -1.555685  1.666978 
  2017-01-04   0.974466  NaN      -0.410001 -0.078638
```

I would like to generate a new df without any column that on the last 2 dates give a NaN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and `mask` - get columns if `True`:

```
print (df.loc[:,~df.iloc[-2:].isnull().all()])
                   A         C         D
2017-01-01  0.132003 -0.076467 -1.187678
2017-01-02  1.130127 -1.413681       NaN
2017-01-03  3.546974 -1.555685  1.666978
2017-01-04  0.974466 -0.410001 -0.078638
```

**Explanation**:

First select only last 2 rows by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) or [`tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html):

```
print (df.iloc[-2:])
#alternative
#print (df.tail(2))
                   A   B         C         D
2017-01-03  3.546974 NaN -1.555685  1.666978
2017-01-04  0.974466 NaN -0.410001 -0.078638
```

Check if [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html):

```
print (df.iloc[-2:].isnull())
                A     B      C      D
2017-01-03  False  True  False  False
2017-01-04  False  True  False  False
```

Check if all values are `True`s in columns by [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
print (df.iloc[-2:].isnull().all())
A    False
B     True
C    False
D    False
dtype: bool
```

Invert boollean mask by `~`:

```
print (~df.iloc[-2:].isnull().all())
A     True
B    False
C     True
D     True
dtype: bool
```

EDIT:

Also is possible select another slice by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print (df.loc['2017-01-03':'2017-01-04'])
                   A   B         C         D
2017-01-03  3.546974 NaN -1.555685  1.666978
2017-01-04  0.974466 NaN -0.410001 -0.078638

print (df.loc[:,~df.loc['2017-01-03':'2017-01-04'].isnull().all()])
                   A         C         D
2017-01-01  0.132003 -0.076467 -1.187678
2017-01-02  1.130127 -1.413681       NaN
2017-01-03  3.546974 -1.555685  1.666978
2017-01-04  0.974466 -0.410001 -0.078638
```